# Mysql sum of time difference between two actions

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate the difference between the time of particular actions. I tried `Max(date)` and `Min(date)` and taking inner join of them with whole table but that only give me the upper and lower bound. How will I fetch the intermediate points also and sum of the difference in time.

For example

```
start 05:00:00
end   05:10:00
start 06:00:00
end   06:10:00
```

So, for this case answer should be 20 mins but I'm getting 1 hr and 10 mins. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include your sample data in table format?  Kind of hard to follow what you want here.

Comment: Add examples/code/references/research if you want us to help you quicker. Refer to [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Action   Time
Start      05:00:00
End        05:10:00
Start      06:00:00
End        06:10:00

So, Adding time difference will be 20 mins

Comment: We need to know the table layout to be able to answer efficiently. Edit it into your original question :)

Comment: so how you know which end correspond to each start?

Comment: @juan , it's like for every start ,the next upcoming end will be taken into consideration. In between them , there may be different actions also.And if their is only start or only end time is given then answer would be zero.

Comment: can you add a column id autonumeric? is the easiest way to solve this